# What is the meaning of "var=${str=expr}" in linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell

What is the meaning of "var=${str=expr}" in linux shell? Who can explain it for me specifically?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `var=${str:=expr}`? What shell specifically, `bash`, `zsh`, `fish`?

Comment: @DanielBeck: Both are valid in POSIX /bin/sh; the one without colon is just much less useful and rarely seen in wild.

Comment: @grawity - Thanks for that: I had reached the conclusion that in bash **=** was behaving as **:=**, but I did not know about the POSIX specification. The bash manual pages make no mention of it.

Comment: @grawity I can not find useful information about that in man page. That's why I ask for help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See "Parameter Expansion" in `man bash`:

> `${parameter:=word}`
>                 Assign Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is assigned  to
>                 parameter.   The  value of parameter is then substituted.  Positional parameters and special
>                 parameters may not be assigned to in this way.

The colon is explained above:

> When not performing substring expansion, using the forms documented below, bash tests for a parameter that is unset or null.  Omitting the colon results in a test  only  for  a  parameter  that  is
>          unset.

Evidence:

```
var=${str=expr}
echo $var
echo $str
```

Output:

```
expr
expr
```

Comment: Very good explanation! "Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset." seems right as well in ${parameter:=word}, ${parameter:-word} and ${parameter:+word}. Am I right?@chroba However, it is not very often to see the form without colon and therefore many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -3):

In bash you can use $( ) to start a task in a subshell.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
foo=${ls}
echo $foo
```

This script will fill the variable $foo with the result of `ls`.
(and `echo $foo` will show you the content).

Now to your more specifiuc question. I did not know the result either so I tested it, assuming that with 'linux shell' you means bash, which is the default shell on my linux distributions.

I created the following file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
foo=${str="test 1 2 3"}
echo $foo
```

and ran it:

```
> ./test t
test 1 2 3
```

It appears  to assign the value iun the string (or in your expression) to the variable **and** to return that value to the parent script.

To recap:

- A new shell will be started
- That new shell will run the command `str=expr`
- The parent shell will get the result as output.
- The parent shell stores that result in $var.

Comment: You're confusing `$( )`, the subshell operator, with `${ }`, the variable expansion operator. They do the same thing in Makefiles but not in shell.

Comment: Ah. Darn. That and a poor screen in which { and ( look the same.